# Problema no javascript com método vindo da controller por session

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é o erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Bem o que passa é seguinte:

Faço uma busca em um WS. No retorno dessa busca, eu monto um html e jogo na minha view (cshtml). Bem, isso funciona.

Aí fiz uns filtros para buscar dentro da minha session, essa informações. Digamos que na minha session, eu tenho 29 Hotéis. Aí, pelo filtro de nome do hotel(um TextBox) eu seleciono um Hotel (Há um auto complete, que tá funcionando). Seleciono o hotel. No `OnBlur` do `textbox`, eu chamo uma função Jquery para carregar o hotel escolhido no textbox.

Ela carrega e nesse momento, eu pego o mesmo html que funciona na primeira carregada, dá esse erro. Eu já não sei mais o que fazer. Os código das funções que carregam o html são grandes, por isso não os postei, mas posso fazê-lo, se quiserem.

Meu searchResult que dá erro na busca

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FiltroGeral(string[] refeicoes, string hotel, string[] categoria)
{
    OfferV2[] pesquisaHotel = ((OfferV2[])SessaoUtil.Recuperar("PegaHotelPacote"));

    List<object> searchResult = new List<object>();

    if (refeicoes != null)
    {
        pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => refeicoes.Contains(x.CategoryId)).ToArray();
    }

    if (hotel != "")
    {
        pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => hotel.Contains(x.ProductName)).ToArray();
    }

    if (categoria != null)
    {
         pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => categoria.Contains(x.CategoryId)).ToArray();
    }
    searchResult.Add(pesquisaHotel);
    return Json(new { searchResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Esse é minha jquery

```
function FiltroGeral() {

        var Refeicoes = [];
        var Hotel = [];
        var Categoria = [];
        var str;
        var filtro;
        var cont = 1;
        var count = 1;
        var camas = [];
        var strHotel;
        var strCategoria;
        var valor = 0;
        var menorValor = 0;
        var parcelas;
        var qQuartos;

        dados = []

        for (var i = 0; i < filtroPesquisa.chkcategoria.length; i++) {

            if (filtroPesquisa.chkcategoria[i].checked) {

                Categoria.push(filtroPesquisa.chkcategoria[i].value);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < filtroPesquisa.chkrefeicao.length; i++) {

            if (filtroPesquisa.chkrefeicao[i].checked) {

                Refeicoes.push(filtroPesquisa.chkrefeicao[i].value);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Hotel/FiltroGeral',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ refeicoes: Refeicoes, hotel: $("#txtNomeHotel").val(), categoria: Categoria, Min: $("#ValorMin").val().replace(".", "").replace(",00", ""), Max: $("#ValorMax").val().replace(".", "").replace(",00", "") }),
            success: function (data) {

                $(data.searchResult).each(function () {

                    alert(ProductName);

                    //menorValor = this.SubOfferGroups[0].AnswerOffersList[0].SalePrice.Value;

                    //$(this.SubOfferGroups).each(function () {

                    //    $(this.AnswerOffersList).each(function () {

                    //        menorValor = Math.min(this.SalePrice.DefaultValue, this.SalePrice.DefaultValue);
                    //    });
                    //});

                    if ($('#ValorHotel').val() != 0) {
                        menorValor = menorValor.toFixed(2) / $('#ValorHotel').val();
                        parcelas = $('#ValorHotel').val() + ' x'
                    }

                    str += '<div class="conteudo"> ';//Div inicial geral, fechar após tudo

                    str += '<div class="grid_11 margin-left-clear">';
                    str += '<div>';
                    str += '<h1>';
                    str += this.ProductName;
                    str += '        </h1>';
                    str += '<div class="valor">' + parcelas + ' ' + menorValor.toFixed(2) + '</div>'; // Inserir o valor com o parcelamento aqui
                    str += '<p>' + this.ShortDescription + '</p>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div class="grid_8 margin-right-clear">';
                    str += '<div class="img-detalhes-hotel">';

                    str += '<img src="' + this.ImageList[0].URL + '" width="290" height="178" />';

                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div class="grid_19 row margin-bottom-10">';
                    str += '<div class="tab-detalhes-produto">';
                    str += '<a href="#fotos-0' + cont + '">Fotos</a>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div class="tab-detalhes-produto">';
                    str += '<a href="#mapa-0' + cont + '">Mapa</a>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div class="tab-detalhes-produto">';
                    str += '<a href="#servicos-0' + cont + '">Servicos</a>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div class="tab-detalhes-produto">';
                    str += '<a href="#selecionar-quartos-0' + cont + '">Selecionar apartamento</a>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div id="fotos-0' + cont + '" class="grid_19 fotos">';
                    str += '<div class="css3slider">';

                    if (this.ImageList.length > 0) {
                        $(this.ImageList).each(function () {

                            str += '       <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="' + cont + 'id' + count + '" checked="checked" />';
                            str += '       <label for="' + cont + 'id' + count + '">';
                            str += '            <img src="' + this.URL + '" />';
                            str += '        </label>';
                            str += '        <img src="' + this.URL + '" width="390" height="262" />';

                            count++;
                        });
                    }

                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div id="mapa-0' + cont + '" class="grid_19 mapa-localizacao-hotel">';
                    str += '<div class="map-canvas" data-opt=' + ' {"txtLatitude":' + this.Latitude + ',"txtLongitude":' + this.Longitude + '}' + ' style="display: block;width: 750px;height: 300px;"></div>';
                    str += '</div>';


                    str += '<div id="servicos-0' + cont + '" class="grid_19 servicos-hotel">';
                    str += '<p>' + this.Description + '</p>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div id="selecionar-quartos-0' + cont + '" class="grid_19 selecionar-quartos">';
                    str += '<div class="grid_18 margin-left-15">';
                    str += '<h1>Selecione seus quartos de acordo com sua preferência</h1>';

                    $(this.SubOfferGroups).each(function () {

                        $(this.AnswerOffersList).each(function () {

                            valor = this.SalePrice.Value;

                            if (valor == "") {
                                valor = 0;
                            }

                            if ($('#ValorHotel').val() != 0) {

                                valor = valor.toFixed(2) / $('#ValorHotel').val();
                            }

                            str += '<div class="display-table border-bottom-cinza">';

                            str += '<div class="display-table">';
                            str += '<div class="grid_8">';
                            str += '<div class="valor">';
                            str += '<input type="checkbox" value="1" />';
                            str += this.ProductName + ' ' + parcelas + ' ' + valor.toFixed(2);
                            str += '</div>';
                            str += '</div>';

                            str += '<div class="grid_5">';
                            str += '<select class="select-group">';
                            str += '<option>Qtd. quartos</option>';

                            for (var i = 1; i < $("#Quartos").val() + 1; i++) {

                                if (i == 1)
                                    str += '<option>' + i + ' quarto</option>';
                                else
                                    str += '<option>' + i + ' quartos</option>';
                                if (i == $("#Quartos").val())
                                    break;
                            }
                            str += '</select>';
                            str += '</div>';


                            str += '<div class="grid_4 selecionar-quartos-adicionais">';
                            str += '<a href="#dados-adicionais-quarto-0' + cont + '">+ informações</a>';
                            str += '</div>';
                            str += '</div>';

                            str += '<div id="dados-adicionais-quarto-0' + cont + '" class="dados-adicionais-quarto">';
                            str += '<div class="grid_11">';
                            str += '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">';
                            str += '<thead>';
                            str += '<tr>';
                            str += '<td>Pessoas</td>';
                            str += '<td>Data</td>';
                            str += '<td>Preço</td>';
                            str += '</tr>';
                            str += '</thead>';

                            var adt = $('#txtAdulto').val();
                            var cri = $('#txtCrianca').val();

                            str += '<tbody>';
                            str += '<tr>';
                            str += '<td>' + (adt > 0 ? adt + ' Adulto(s)' : "") + ' ' + (cri > 0 ? cri + ' Criança(s)' : "") + '</td>';
                            str += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
                            str += '<td>' + this.SalePrice.Value.toFixed(2) + '</td>';
                            str += '</tr>';
                            str += '</tbody>';

                            str += '</table>';
                            str += '</div>';
                            str += '<div class="grid_4">';

                            str += '<p>aqui será inserido o texto referente a serviços inclusos e politica de cancelamento</p>';
                            str += '</div>';
                            str += '</div>';
                            str += '</div>';

                        });
                    });
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '</div>';

                    dados.push(str);

                    cont++;

                    str = "";

                    $("#Pagination").pagination(dados.length, {

                        items_per_page: 5,
                        num_display_entries: 1,
                        num_edge_entries: 1,
                        callback: pageselectCallback

                    });
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("erro");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Informe a linha que dá erro. Ou apenas o trecha da função que dá esse erro.

Comment: str += '<div class="grid_8 margin-right-clear">';
                    str += '<div class="img-detalhes-hotel">';
                    str += '<img src="' + (this.ImageList.length != 0 ? this.ImageList[0].URL : 0) + '" width="290" height="178" />';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>'; O erro da no this.ImageList, aliás tudo que vem no meu searchResult, diz que ´´e undefined

Comment: this.ImageList é indefinido nesse caso. Verifique o contexto, talvez até a referencia do "this" esteja undefined. Qual é o método que carrega o contexto deste "this" ?

Comment: Se fosse o `this`, então o erro seria `Cannot read property 'ImageList' of undefined`... a não ser que ele tenha algo do tipo `this[0]`, ai sim poderia ser.

Comment: Tem sim: this.ImageList[0]

Comment: @pnet: Agora sim, com todas as informações é possível responder a pergunta. Sempre poste o código, ou trechos relevantes do código para obter ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Sem saber exatamente o código em que o erro ocorre</s><sup>(OP adicionou linha do erro)</sup>, o que posso fazer é tentar explicar em que situações este erro ocorre.

Se uma variável está definida, mas não possui um valor nela, ou seja, é `undefined` então não será possível:

- ler propriedades dessa variável
- chamar métodos nessa variável
- usar índices nessa variável
- usar chaves associativas nessa variável

**Exemplo da condição em que o erro ocorre**

```
var array;
var valor = array[0];
```

### Revisão do código

Seu código está com alguns problemas, que você pode não ter percebido.

No C#:

- a variável `searchResult` é uma lista de objetos, e quando você usa o método `Add`, somente um objeto está sendo adicionado. Esse objeto sendo adicionado é um array... isso quer dizer que o elemento 0 dessa lista é um array de vários objetos, é como se fosse uma lista dentro de outra lista.
- Você chama `ToArray` muitas vezes, o que torna o código menos eficiente. O melhor seria operar diretamente sobre um IQueryable ou IEnumerable. Como sua fonte de dados já retorna um array, então podemos usar o IEnumerable, e então aplicar todos os filtros sucessivamente, chamando `ToArray` ou `ToList` somente uma vez.
- Ao retornar o JSON, não existe necessidade de criar um objeto só para conter uma única variável... poderia retornar a lista diretamente: ``
- A action está marcada com o atributo `HttpPost`, o que impede de ser feito um `GET` neste método. Então não há motivo para usar a opção `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.
- A verificação da variável `hotel` contra `""` não é suficiente, pois ela poderia ser nula, ou conter apenas espaços em branco. Então o melhor é usar `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` para fazer a verificação.

Como ficaria o C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FiltroGeral(string[] refeicoes, string hotel, string[] categoria)
{
    var pesquisaHotel = ((IEnumerable<OfferV2>)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("PegaHotelPacote"));

    if (refeicoes != null)
    {
        pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => refeicoes.Contains(x.CategoryId));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hotel))
    {
        pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => hotel.Contains(x.ProductName));
    }

    if (categoria != null)
    {
        pesquisaHotel = pesquisaHotel.Where(x => categoria.Contains(x.CategoryId));
    }

    return Json(pesquisaHotel.ToList());
}
```

Tendo o código dessa forma, no javascript poderia fazer assim:

- ao invés de usar `$(data.searchResult).each(` poderia aplicar direto ao `data`:

  ```
  $(data).each(function () {
  ```
- dentro dessa função, o `this` seria o próprio objeto equivalente ao `OfferV2`... do jeito que estava antes, isso não era verdade, por casusa do problema que eu apontei sobre uma lista dentro de outra lista.

Em suma, o erro está dentro do código C#, no momento em que adiciona uma lista dentro da outra:

```
searchResult.Add(pesquisaHotel);
```

Comment: Ok, Miguel, entendi. Mas veja meu cenário. Tudo isso vem de uma session que está carregada. Se eu dou um break no meu searchResult, existe todos os dados lá. Então, não deveria ser undefined. Há algo que eu não estou entendendo

Comment: O que é essa `searchResult`? Como ela se relaciona com o contexto atual? Você não mencionou nada sobre esta variável.

Comment: searchResult é o retorno de minha controller. Há dois métodos. O primeiro quando eu entro na página e depois de estar na página, vem a busca e retorna esse searchResult com as informações de busca. Posso postar, mas na seção comentário não dá pelo limite de caracteres. Vou editar meu post e enviar esses caras, mas como eu disse, pode ficar muito grande.

Comment: Tudo isso é carregado em uma session e depois a busca é feita na session

Comment: Poderia postar por favor o código da chamada AJAX, que é feita no javascript? Tenho desconfiança de que o erro esteja lá.

Comment: Postei toda a minha jquery

Comment: @pnet: atualizei a resposta com alguns pontos referentes ao código postado.